# How to move around warp points without effecting other points

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture, transform

I'm trying to warp a treebark texture following the grey guidelines as seen below:

[image]

But when I try to move each warp "line" into position, it effects all the other warp lines, making it impossible to place all lines in their respective guidelines. Under you can see me hopelessly trying to warp the picture:

[image]

Comment: I don't think what you are asking for is an option. That's just the way Warp works..:-?

Comment: Oh well... thats stupid

Answer (score -1):

you can make this by split your layer to 3 layer

[image]

and set under this layer original layer to be background

Comment: This is not good since (even it you place the background below) it will still create visible cut-like lines when using wrap on them. And using a soft eraser on the margins will not help either since it will be a noticeable difference in the texture direction.